# Usage of "on" in "fire on"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fire (at, on, in, to) target](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72848/fire-at-on-in-to-target)

I saw the following sentence on Guardian.co.uk:

> US navy fires on boat near Dubai port.

Is *on* being used here as a preposition to make a link between the fire and the boat, or is it part of the phrasal verb — if it exists — *fires on*?

Can you give some examples where *on* is being used like the one referred above?

Comment: If they had fired _over_ the boat, then chances are they'd lower their guns, and then fire _on_ the boat.

Comment: Sorry J.R, but I can't understand the differences between fired over vs fired on :S

Comment: @utxeee if they fire *over* it, they've missed their target.

Comment: Fired _on_ is like fired _at_; you aim at the boat.  Fired _over_ means you aim above the target, perhaps to give a warning shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would technically be a prepositional phrase, not part of the verb since you could do without it. `US Navy 'fires' 'on boat' near Dubai port.` However, that would then mean they were on the boat when they were firing, which is assumed since it is the US Navy. Therefore, you're right, it would be verb phrase. `US Navy 'fires on' boat near Dubai port.`

Comment: I don't think the 'on' in 'fire on' is acting as a preposition. If 'He fired on the boat' is parsed as [[NP he] [VP [V fired] [PP on the boat]]], that means that he fired, and the place he did it is 'on the boat'. And that's not the meaning. the meaning is he did something to the boat? What did he do to the boat? He -fired on- it. It's a phrasal verb here.

Comment: Fixed. You're right, and I totally changed the sentance when I diagrammed it!